# How come spatial objects can't be used in a VALUES statement?

Tags: sql-server, spatial

How come you can do,

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
  ('foo')  -- or (1), etc.
) AS t(x);
```

But, not

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES
  ( geography::Point(0,0,4326) )
) AS t(geog);
```

I was trying to answer [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/266741/6052), but had to create a temp table instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What result are you expecting? It seems to work OK for me:

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM (VALUES
>   ('foo')  -- or (1), etc.
> ) AS t(x);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | x   |
> | :-- |
> | foo |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM ( VALUES
>   ( geography::Point(0,0,4326) )
> ) AS t(geog);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | geog        |
> | :---------- |
> | POINT (0 0) |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c8df6bb9b60959f86b54ea7c8a46018c)*